# How to generate an OpenPGP Signed Message with GPG?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, command-line-arguments

In [RFC 4880](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880), there is [section 11.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-11.3) which specifies the different formats an OpenPGP Message block can have:

```
11.3.  OpenPGP Messages

   An OpenPGP message is a packet or sequence of packets that
   corresponds to the following grammatical rules (comma represents
   sequential composition, and vertical bar separates alternatives):

   OpenPGP Message :- Encrypted Message | Signed Message |
                      Compressed Message | Literal Message.

   Compressed Message :- Compressed Data Packet.

   Literal Message :- Literal Data Packet.

   ESK :- Public-Key Encrypted Session Key Packet |
          Symmetric-Key Encrypted Session Key Packet.

   ESK Sequence :- ESK | ESK Sequence, ESK.

   Encrypted Data :- Symmetrically Encrypted Data Packet |
         Symmetrically Encrypted Integrity Protected Data Packet

   Encrypted Message :- Encrypted Data | ESK Sequence, Encrypted Data.

   One-Pass Signed Message :- One-Pass Signature Packet,
               OpenPGP Message, Corresponding Signature Packet.

   Signed Message :- Signature Packet, OpenPGP Message |
               One-Pass Signed Message.

   In addition, decrypting a Symmetrically Encrypted Data packet or a
   Symmetrically Encrypted Integrity Protected Data packet as well as
   decompressing a Compressed Data packet must yield a valid OpenPGP
   Message.
```

Is there some way, through commandline arguments, to generate a `Signed Message` using GPG? Note that a `Signed Message` is **not** the type shown on [XKCD](http://xkcd.com/1181/). That is a `Cleartext Signature`, described in [section 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-7) of the RFC. An armored `Signed Message` will have the header `-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----`.

The closest I can get is by using `gpg -s`, which generates a compressed data packet that encapsulates a One-pass Signature Packet, Literal Data Packet, Signature Packet. However, I do not believe that it should be compressed, so it seems that either GPG is compressing when it shouldn't, or GPG is outputting compressed messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GnuPG compresses (at least plain text) messages by default. If you do not want it to compress messages, set the compression level to 0 using the option `--compress-level 0`. From `man gpg`:

```
--compress-level n

[...] A value of 0 for n disables compression.
```

Using `-s` together with a compression level of 0 will output the non-compressed signed message, actually a one-pass signed message.

Compression of a message is expected behavior. [RFC 4880, chapter 2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-2.3) states:

> ### Compression
>
> OpenPGP implementations SHOULD compress the message after applying
> the signature but before encryption. [...]